# When I use ldapadd I get a response with possible options. How can I fix this?

Tags: linux, fedora, ldap, openldap

```
sudo ldapadd -x -D cn=Manager, dc=localhost,dc=localdomain -W -f /home/liveuser/basedomain.ldif
```

Is the code that I type into Fedora31 terminal and the response that I get back is jsut all the available options to use with ldapp even though I have -x -D -W -f. Anyone know why I may be getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`cn=Manager, dc=localhost,dc=localdomain` should be a single option-argument to `-D` option. There's a space there which makes your shell split the string into two words, two arguments. This breaks the syntax. Then `ldapadd` doesn't understand the command and informs you what syntax it expects.

Remove this space. In general quote if necessary.